# creating multiple subplots simultaneously

Tags: matlab, simulink, subplot

How do I create multiple subplots simultaneously,
for example, I have

```
while i < 4
   kS = kS_array(i);
   bS = bS_array(i);
   sim('sim_1');
   subplot(3,1,i), plot(time,x);
   %now i want to create another subplot for F(force wrt time)
   % something like subplot_2(3,1,i), plot(time, F)
   i=i+1;
end
```

I am simulating simulink model with different variables and plotting them.
I am a beginner so I want to know if there is any other efficient way to do this.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to make 2 figures, each figure with multiple subplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer

```
figure1 = figure; figure2 = figure;
while i < 4
   kS = kS_array(i);
   bS = bS_array(i);
   sim('sim_1');
   set(0, 'currentfigure', figure1);
   subplot(3,1,i), plot(time,x);
   set(0, 'currentfigure', figure2);
   subplot(3,1,i), plot(time, FT);
   i=i+1;
end
```

This works the way I want it.

Comment: Good for finding the answer for yourself. Actually, the "convential" way to do it is `figure(1)`, `figure(2)`, instead of each `set(...`.